# Clicking on xpath button with Selenium on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

i used Selenium IDE on Firefox to find the  [xpath of buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcLp8.jpg) The next step is to click the button on Python. I tried inserting the xpath in the code below, but no luck. I do not know how to change the xpath so that it fits to the code below.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('')
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Be careful with quotes and double quotes, use double outside and simple inside, for example "//*[@class='myClass']"

Comment: Thanks, so i type in browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="button"]') , but how do i click for example the element with xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[209]

Comment: Add html section of the button if possible.You should get another selector manually, this selector is not reliable at all,If any of the previous button is changing you will click the wrong button. Try browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[209]")

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working Perfectly, have a good day!

Comment: @lauda you should provide it is an answer and OP need to accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with quotes and double quotes, use double outside and simple inside, for example

```
"//*[@class='myClass']"
```

Try this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[20‌​9]")
```

You should get the selector manually in another way, this selector is not reliable at all, if any of the previous button is missing you will click the wrong button.